# Getting measure to only show positive values in matrix Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm new to DAX. Looking for your expertise. Looked all over the web but couldn't find a proper solution.

I have a matrix that shows several factories and it's inventories, the rows being factory and SKU. I've created a measure that's the difference between two other measures. The overall idea is: I have a inventory quantity and an orders volume. I defined a "balance" measure that's **`inventory - sales`**. That is, what is still left for sale.

Normally it works fine, but when I have a negative value in balance, things get messed up. The subtotal in the factory row sums all the numbers, including negatives, giving me a balance subtotal that is smaller than it's supposed to be. I can't count the negatives. So I've tried to solve this by defining the measure as

```
Balance = IF([Inventory]>[Sales],[Inventory] - [Sales],BLANK())
```

Now this works fine visually to display only the positive values in balance, but still sums up the negatives in the factory subtotal.

How can I make this measure to only show and sum up the positives?

I appreciate your help.

*P.S.: the inventory and sales measures are basically SUM's of different tables for simplicity and understanding by my part*

[Matrix with measures. The columns are "Estoque" as inventory, "Embarque programado total" as sales and "Saldo Disp. Venda" as the balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJFso.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was able to find a solution through trial and error. I changed my measure to (FatoEstoque is the table that contains the inventory numbers):

`Balance= CALCULATE([Inventory]-[Sales],FILTER(FatoEstoque,[Inventory]>[Sales]))`

Although I'm not even sure why it works (lol), it works! So I'm not complaining. This measure only sums up the positive values, showing the correct subtotal as I needed.

Filtering the Inventory table to values where [Inventory]>[Sales] works, but adding another filter with the Sales table and the same condition don't.

Here is an image comparing the results. The new measure is called *SaldVender2*

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure with the below code.

```
Balance = CALCULATE(SUM([Inventory]) - SUM([Sales]), FILTER(Table1, [Inventory]>[Sales]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Although it didn't work. [Inventory] and [Sales] are both measures as well, from different tables.

I tried removing the ``SUM`` part, as in a measure you don't need it, but I don't know what table to use in the ``FILTER``, since the measures are SUMs of distinct tables. The results of your suggestion were the same as those of my measure mentioned in the post =/

Comment: Balance = CALCULATE([Inventory] - [Sales],  [Inventory]>[Sales])

Comment: That also doesn't work, as the CALCULATE function doesn't accept this kind of filtering. But you and @Dharman helped me get to the solution, so thanks!

Comment: I was not aware of the table names. Anyways I am glad you figured it out. Thanks.